# Propositional Logic in Prolog - Incorrect Representations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

There is a certain premise which I am unable to represent correctly as propositional logic:

1. "When I play basketball, I wear my sneakers; otherwise, I never wear it."

   `(PlayBasketBall -> WearSneakers) <-> (-PlayBasketBall -> -WearSneakers)`

What changes do I need to make in order to represent it correctly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does the `<->` mean "if and only if"? I think you want an "and" there instead. Or you could restate the whole thing as just `PlayBasketball <-> WearSneakers`.

Comment: I see, restating as the latter like you stated worked out!